# Different font size in Firefox vs. IE & Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, font-size

my website in developing process looking in Mozilla Firefox with same font-size declaration, margin & padding and different font-families always a few smaller than in Google Chrome or Internet Explorer.

For example letter "O":

```
IE: 27 px height
Chrome: 27 px height
Firefox: 24 px height
```

All developer tools show font-size:38px;. I've also tried to fix the issue with em values. But it's the same issue.

Any ideas how I can find out where the issue is?

[image: Different font size Chrome]
[image: Different font size Firefox]

Comment: Please share the online link of your website.

Comment: I have to wonder... does this really matter? Is cross-browser identity really that important? Cuz there's a lot of browsers out there, all with their own font rendering quirks...

Comment: Just made a [test](http://jsfiddle.net/Lteq628r/2/), in Chome and Firefox, which confirms the differences both with fonts in px in pt units. Using line-height cound at least make lines the same height, but does not solve the fact the font is bigger/smaller in some browsers.

Comment: Blue line: 32 px Firefox, 31 px Google Chrome
Red line: 32 px Firefox, 31 px Google Chrome

I've added font-family:Arial.

Comment: I've tested the last 1,5 hours and found the mistake. My Password Manager Addon was the issue maker! Deactivating it all works correct.

Answer (score 1):

i think this would be help for you.

```
<html>
<head>


<!--[if IE]>
<style>
body{
background-color:red;
}

</style>
<![endif]-->

<style>
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
body{
background-color:green;
}
}
body{ 
background-color:yellow;
}
</style>

</head>

</html>
```

Comment: Issue found! The password manager was the source of trouble! Thanks and sry for aksing.